# Ist "Ich fahre NICHT nach Berlin" ein Fall der betonten Negation?

Tags: word-order, negation

Ich habe bei vielen Internet-Webseiten gelesen, dass die Negation *nicht* vor einem Teil eines Satzes stehen muss, wenn man diesen bestimmten Teil negieren will. Laut diesen Webseiten heißt dieses Phänomen die betonte Negation. Man muss durch die Korrektur ein *sondern* hinzufügen. Ich habe jedoch Zweifel bei folgendem Satz:

> Ich fahre nicht nach Berlin.

Ist dieser Satz ein Beispiel von betonter Negation? Wenn das so wäre, dann wäre der unbetonte Fall:

> ich fahre nach Berlin nicht.

Laut deutschegrammatik20.de ist der Satz *Ich fahre nicht nach Berlin* ein Beispiel von unbetonter Negation. Auf dieser Webseite wird besagt, dass in diesem Fall die Negation vor der Satzklammer steht. Ich kann aber dabei keine Satzklammer identifizieren, da es nur ein finites untrennbares Verb gibt.

Comment: Ich habe wenig Ahnung von Grammatik, daher Kommentar: Der erste Satz ist einfaches gutes Deutsch. Der zweite Satz ist halbes "Yoda-Deutsch" - oder die Übernahme einer gewissen englischen Humor-Protestform: "ich mache xy - nicht". Was m.E. viel relevanter ist: das `nicht` an korrekter Stelle wird schnell ignoriert. Daher suche ich nach Formulierungen, die es hervorheben: "kein...". Oder hier: "Ich fahre nach xy, nicht nach Berlin. / Ich fahre nicht nach Berlin sondern nach xy" - ich will vom Satzbau mehr mitgeben als das `nicht`. u.a. bei https://www.global-translations.ch/de/blog/negation-ii

Comment: _"ich fahre nach Berlin nicht."_ ist Nonsens als eigenständiger Satz. Wo hast Du das gelesen, gehört?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich habe beobachtet, dass diese Nonsenskonstruktion zunimmt, weil Leute damit Ironie/Sarkasmus deutlich machen wollen (um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden). Das Phänomen habe ich zuerst im Internet (schriftlich) beobachtet, aber ich hatte auch eine jüngere Kollegin, die das in ihren gesprochenen Wortschatz übernommen hat, à la: "Die Idee vom Chef ist ja wieder super - nicht." Will sagen, gewöhn Dich besser dran ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es kann hier so vielfältig verneint werden, aber in den meisten Fällen ist bei diesem Beispeil die Betonung wichtiger als die Stellung (die gar nicht so stark variieren kann):

> Ich fahre nicht nach *Berlin*

... sondern nach Hamburg

> Ich fahre nicht *nach* Berlin

... sondern von Berlin nach anderswo

> Ich *fahre* nicht nach Berlin

... sondern nehme den Flieger

> Ich fahre *nicht* nach Berlin

... sondern bleibe daheim

> Nicht *ich* fahre nach Berlin

... sondern mein Freund Herbert.

Nur bei der letzten Variante wird durch die Stellung vor "Ich" eindeutig geklärt, dass speziell das Subjekt "verneint" werden soll. (Verneint wird natürlich immer noch die Aussage, also der Satz als Ganzes, aber es wird deutlicher, in welcher Richtung sich ein - möglicherweise unausgesprochenes - "sondern" anschließen kann).

Comment: In seltenen Fällen würde ich auch sagen `Nicht *nach Berlin* fahre ich.` - das ist dann schon heftiges Betonungsrumgespiele.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm And (answering for a friend ;-) ): "*Fahren* tu' ich nich' nach Berlin, *fliegen* tu' ich!"

Answer (score 1):

> Ich fahre nicht nach Berlin.

Dieser Satz ist (im Gegensatz zu dem anderen) grammatikalisch korrekt und es ist unbetont. Das "nicht" steht vor der Satzklammer. Die Satzklammer ist hier die Präposition "nach Berlin".

Allerdings kann man durch hinzufügen von "sondern" durchaus eine betonte Negation daraus machen:

> Ich fahre nicht nach Berlin, sondern nach Hamburg.

Comment: Es stimmt, dass das "nicht" vor der Satzklammer steht. "Nach Berlin" ist aber im engeren Sinne keine Präposition, sondern ein Präpositionalobjekt. Es ist eine schade, dass bei vielen Webseiten keine gute Erklärung zu der Beziehung zwischen Präpositionalobjekten und Satzklammer gibt.